# Duplicating Layers to new, independent layers in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, layers, duplication

I am currently working on a rough freight railway station planning project in QGIS 3 and it's output should be different "alternatives" (as layer groups) with different layers to each.

For example
Alternative 1: 500m rails and two railway switches.
Alternative 2: 300m rails and just one switch, etc.

In total there will be 5 alternative designs in the project. Every alternative is one layer group, every attribute / feature (read here, rail line, road) of the alternatives is a layer (withing the group).

Since the alternatives are closely related to each other, I would like to copy a layer group with it's layers and modify the other alternatives from them.

For example, I want to use Alternative 1 as "foundation" for the other alternatives and remove one of the switches and shorten the railway line.

Yet, QGIS keeps the same source, which results that if you edit the layer in Alternative 1, it will also affect Alternative 2.

So how the small help I need is an advice on how to copy layers, and then save them "independently" so changes wont affect the different alternatives.

Comment: Just copy the existing files, either directly in the folder you saved them in, or by exporting the data.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works.
but as I understand it then, if imported from and exported gpkg, I will have to "redesign" the symbolization (colors of lines, etc.) manually again for each variant?

Comment: No, you may rightclick a layer, choose style -> copy style and paste it to the new layer.

Comment: Perfect Erik, thanks so much.
And now a bonus question; is it possible to edit the .gpkg somewhere to delete "layers" that are unused but still in the file?

Comment: Can't answer that one, sorry, I'm still mostly using shapefiles.

Comment: @Félix you may use DB Manager plugin to delete table from gpkg. First right click in db manager on GeoPackage and add a new connection (if your gpkg not in the list). Look for your table in the tree and right click on it and Delete from the menu. You can use the QGIS browser panel also  for this in a similar way.

Comment: You may use Export / Save Features As from the popup menu of the layer in the layers panel to duplicate a layer with other name.

Comment: It seems like you have a good solution figured out but I often just add a scenario field then duplicate the feature that I want to modify and assign it to the new scenario and filter out the others.